# Make a object/variable available globally in the shell xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using xamarin forms shell, in the footer I have a ContentView [UserView], Bindcontext to LoginViewModel, the login is successful.

```
<Shell 
...
    <Shell.FlyoutFooter>
        <control:UserView/>
    </Shell.FlyoutFooter>
...
```

I would like to make the object [User] universally available to other contentviews, going through parameter serializing is very expensive:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"SomePage?serialized={Uri.EscapeDataString(serialized)}");
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"OthersLotsPages?serialized={Uri.EscapeDataString(serialized)}");
```

Is it possible to make this object [User] available as a service or something like that, which can be accessed by all pages without needing to serializing? If possible, what is the best way?

**LoginViewModel.cs**

```
    public User _user { get; set; }
    public User UserTemp
    {
        get { return _user ; }
        set
        {
           _user = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("UserTemp");
        }
    }
```

...

```
private async void Login()
{
...
      UserTemp = await UserService.Login(username, password); //Let UserTemp accessible for other all contentpages after login success
...
}
```

Image 1

[image: Image 1]

Image 2

[image: Image 2]

Image 3

[image: Image 3]

Comment: make it a property of your App class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Application` subclass has a static `Properties` dictionary which can be used to store data, in particular for use in the `OnStart`, `OnSleep`, and `OnResume` methods. This can be accessed from anywhere in your Xamarin.Forms code using `Application.Current.Properties`.

The `Properties` dictionary uses a string key and stores an object value.

You could save the data like:

```
Application.Current.Properties ["User"] = YourUser;
```

then you could get it in the `OnAppearing()` method of your page:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
 {
    base.OnAppearing();
    if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("User"))
    {
        User user= (User)Application.Current.Properties["user"];
    }
}
```

the more you could look at [Properties dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#properties-dictionary).